# jQuery plugin, unbind elements and rerun the plugin

Tags: jquery, ajax, xhtml

I'm making a simple plugin that activates when certain hyperlinks are clicked so for example:

```
// actives the plugin for an anchor with class mylink
jQuery('a.mylink').c_podsystem();

// the plugin
(function($){

  $.fn.c_podsystem = function(opt) {  
    var opt = $.extend(opt);

    return this.each(function() {


         jQuery(this).click(function(e){
              // do something
         }

    });
 };
})(jQuery);
```

In some instances I need to rerun the plugin after an ajax success (so anchors that might be returned in the ajax with the class **mylink** will work with the plugin).

However, if you just run **jQuery('a.mylink').c_podsystem();** in the ajax callback, it reruns for items already on the page previously binded, which causes the plugin to run twice.

So to combat this I need to unbind all elements **affected** by  return this.each()

Then just rerun **jQuery('a.mylink').c_podsystem()** so it actives all anchors on the page with the class **mylink** from the fresh dom.

How do I unbind the previously affected elements, so I can just rerun the plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would it be possible to adjust your plugin to use [.live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/)?

> Attach a handler to the event for all
>   elements which match the current
>   selector, now and in the future.

Using live you could rework your plugin to the following:

```
(function($) {

    $.fn.c_podsystem = function(opt) {
        var opt = $.extend(opt);
        jQuery(this).live("click", function(e) {
            $("#result").append($(this).text());
        });
    }
})(jQuery);
```

Bind to existing a.mylink

```
jQuery('a.mylink').c_podsystem();
```

Append a new link to the dom

```
$("#links").append($("<a>After Plugin Ran</a>").addClass("mylink"));
```

By using live the click event handler will still function as intended by your plugin.

Example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7jSwK/1/)